# Why in heightForRowAt method my cell is nil?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ExpandablePlaneTableViewCell {
        return 400.0
    }

    return 75.0
}
```

I want to change size of my cell but inside of `heightForRowAt` it cannot see my `cell` and crashed. When I put there `if let` check it does not enter inside of the block and just takes 75.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is? It's too strange for me!
I already set delegate to self. So it call the function but cannot detect my cell there.

**UPDATE**

In my `ExpandablePlaneTableViewCell` I have a variable:

```
var exapanded = false
```

Later in my ViewController: On click on the button in the cell I run my delegate method:

```
func expandViewButtonTapped(_ sender: ExpandablePlaneTableViewCell, for indexPath: IndexPath) {
    sender.exapanded = true
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```

and after I want to expand it and reload the cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "expandableCell", for: indexPath) as! ExpandablePlaneTableViewCell

    cell.delegate = self
    cell.indexPath = indexPath

    return cell
}
```

Comment: It cannot fetch the cell or the cell is never of type `ExpandablePlaneTableViewCell`? Can you check this please?

Comment: Do not do that. First `tableView.cellForRow(at:)` will return nil if the cell is not visible.

Comment: Is `tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)` returning nil or is it returning something not castable to `ExpandablePlaneTableViewCell`? You can verify this by debugging the application at that point and seeing what the result of `tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)` is.

Comment: @Larme but I need to know what the cell is it to change its size. I have to check if it was expanded or not

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza it seems it is never of type ExpandablePlaneTableViewCell

Comment: " but I need to know what the cell is it to change its size. I have to check if it was expanded or not" Can't you guess that with your model? Do not rely on view, rely on your model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not attempt to get a cell in `heightForRowAt`. And there certainly is no reason to do so in your case.

You seem to want the height to be one value for certain types of cells and another height for other types.

Simply use the same basic logic you have in `cellForRowAt`, based on the `indexPath`, to determine which height to return. **In other words, base the decision on your data model, not on the cell.**

Comment: and how can I set the height from `cellForRowAt`. It seems I did not get your point =/

Comment: You don't. You return a cell from `cellForRowAt`. You return the height from `heightForRowAt`.

Comment: When you actually create the cell you will have somewhere something like `if expandable: create a cell of type ExpandablePlaneTableViewCell`

Use the same logic. to understand if it is expanded you might want to store the boolean in a dictionary of type [IndexPath: Int] maybe, so that you don't have to rely on the value in the cell that can be reused.

Comment: @J.Doe If my answer doesn't make sense to you at the moment, update your question with your complete `cellForRowAt` method then I can update my answer with a more concrete example.

Comment: @rmaddy I've updated my question. I hope it will help you to better understand me

Comment: You also need to include your `cellForRowAt` method. Your biggest issue is that you can't use the cell to store the "expanded" state. You need to store that state information in the data model used as your table's data source. How else can you set each cell's "expanded" state in `cellForRowAt`?

Comment: @rmaddy Included! Yes. I got your point and you are right about the model. I'll do that. But for now I just want to expand it. Without tracking the state

Comment: @J.Doe That's not an option. Cells get reused as you scroll. Therefore you need to set the "expanded" state of every cell inside your `cellForRowAt` method. And to do that you have to track it in your data model, not the cell. Once that is in place, then you can look at that value in your `heightForRowAt` method to return the correct height, without the need to get a cell.

Comment: so instead of checking the cell variable I'll check inside of the model and according to that expand my cell, right?